# Redirect loop when logging in to appengine

Tags: google-app-engine

(yes - cross-posted from the google-appengine google group...I can't tell if they answer support questions like this there or here or what...it's all kind of a mess :) )

I am having a problem logging in to the appengine console using certain accounts on my google apps domain (but not others).

No matter what browser I use (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE), I get a "too many redirects" error on https://appengine.google.com/start when I try to log in using a specific account.  I have tried resetting all the browsers as well (clearing all cookies, cache, etc - even trying it on a clean install of an OS) - with no luck.  Going directly to https://appengine.google.com/a/domain.name causes the same loop for those accounts.  The same thing happens when running the browsers with privacy mode enabled.

One of the accounts having problems is the user nathan.toone on the k9webprotection.com google apps domain - however we can log in with the user "admin" or the user "build-agent" on the same domain just fine (but not "build.agent" or "user2").  It seems to be all over the place as to which accounts are able to log in without the redirect loop and which ones aren't.

I have contacted google apps for your domain support, and they have said that it is outside their scope.  They very "helpfully" pointed me to https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general - which didn't help *AT ALL*. :(

Again - the odd thing is that there are some of the accounts on the same domain that are able to log in just fine.  Does anyone have any idea what could be happening, or have a way for me to contact someone to get this worked out?  I have found a couple of other people saying they have had this problem, but have not been able to encounter a solution.

-Nathan

Comment: Users of the domain have to be added to the appengine app if you want them to be able to access the dashboard.  Its not clear from your question if the user ids with problems are just trying to login to your app of the dashboard.

Comment: The problem is that they are not able to log in to http://appengine.google.com at all...they can't log in to accept the invitation or anything.

Comment: Can you please file a production report on https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list.